# When using ellipsis to omit list items, is a comma required after the last item before the ellipsis or not?

Tags: punctuation, commas, ellipses

Which, if any, format do you consider preferable?

"10, 11, 12, ... 19, 20."

"Violet, Indigo, ... Orange, Red."

-OR-

"10, 11, 12 ... 19, 20."

"Violet, Indigo ... Orange, Red."

Comment: In mathematical writing a third option would be more usual: commas before and after the ellipsis, ie 9, 10, ..., 14, 15

Comment: @aPaulT So I guess the first style would be better suited for common writing. Thanks.

Comment: 'Better suited' is probably a better analysis than 'more correct' here.

Comment: Sorry; it was the notion of 'preferable' rather than 'right or wrong'; I've edited the question to convey this without sounding strange – 'better suited' needs a comparator: 'better suited' to what?

Comment: How about this:

**"Violet, Indigo... Orange, Red."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the popular style manual *Kate Turabian's A Manual for Writers* (a concise version of the Chicago Manual of Style) does not directly address your specific case, the proper usage can be deduced from similar examples. When word(s) within the middle of a sentence are omitted, three ellipsis dots should be used with a preceding space (e.g., a word . . . has been omitted). If an omission is made directly before the end of the sentence, the terminal punctuation mark remains; the ellipsis comes *after* the punctuation mark (e.g., Is there an omission? . . .). It also shows the following example: "We are fighting for truth; . . . for freedom . . . ; and . . . for survival". It appears that the punctuation of the sentence remains intact, with the ellipsis dots merely taking the place of the missing words. I assume that the example with semicolons could be extended to commas as well, as the semicolons are mid-sentence punctuation (and are occasionally used to separate a list or series of terms). Therefore, if eliding a list of colors, "Violet, . . . Indigo, Red" is more appropriate. I believe for the series of numerals, the proper mathematical notation would be "1, 2, 3, . . . , 19, 20", with a comma *before and after* the ellipsis. There is an **entire chapter** (ch. 14) on mathematical notation (including elided lists) in the full *Chicago Manual of Style, 15th ed.*,  but unfortunately I do not have a copy available for reference. If you need a reference for mathematics in type, then I suggest you look through that chapter. (The *Chicago Manual of Style* is available in the reference section of most libraries.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! Really appreciated.